# Filtering MS Graph request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, filtering

I'm trying to use Graph to get information on a adminstrative unit. I do know the name, but need the identifier for further queries.

I could offcourse NOT filter the request and itterate over the result to find the correct AU. But it seems more elagant to filter te request.

The URL below works, but filter with a "startswith", which does not do the trick for me.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/administrativeUnits?$filter=startswith(displayName,'some name')`

Whenever I try to use operators like eq or equal an error message is the result.
The closest I've gotten to a result is with "endwith". In which case I have to add an header field consistencylevel=eventual and ad $count=true to the URL. But it gives me no result.

Any help on this?
Seemed trivial when I started this. But am at a total loss at the moment.

Peter

Comment: The filter with eq works great on my side. ?$filter=displayName eq 'Unit name' Does the unit name contain any special character? I can try the query with name of your unit.

Comment: Nothing to special: staf-cb. But i've never tried it without parentises.